# How to refresh the CPU cache in the embedded linux system(arm linux)

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, fpga, dma

I am using the zynq development board. Due to the existence of DMA, my CPU cache cannot detect the change of memory. In bare metal development, I can use the cache function provided by xilinx to solve this problem. I want to know whether there is a similar function in linux , and how to use them

In the Linux kernel source, I found this file and functions, how should I use them, which header files should be referenced
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmxtZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mz0K.png)

Comment: A good place to start is [Dynamic DMA mapping](https://docs.kernel.org/core-api/dma-api.html). You shouldn't need to worry about the cache if using DMA consistent/coherent memory buffers. If using streaming/non-coherent memory buffers, the dma_map_..., dma_unmap_..., dma_sync_... family of functions should handle the details of flushing CPU data caches, handling IOMMU and/or DMA bounce buffers, etc.

Comment: Rather than "*refresh the CPU cache*" (which requires coordination with I/O operations), Linux prefers to simply designate a memory page/region as uncacheable. Requesting a DMA-able buffer using the appropriate Linux kernel interfaces (as mentioned by @IanAbbott) will automatically be memory that is not cached (by the CPU), and therefore not require any cache refresh or flushing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a u-dma-buf module for Linux, see [here](https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf). It allows to control the cache behaviour for the region you're mapping. I always use it for communication with AXI masters on the FPGA fabric.