# How linker script files work when generate elf file

Tags: linker, elf

I am using linker script file to generate specific elf file.I add this code to lscript.ld

```
.test : {
    *(.text.ssc_entry)
    *main.o(.text)
    *main.o(.text.*)
} > ins_lmb_bram_if_cntlr_0_Mem_data_lmb_bram_if_cntlr_1_Mem
```

After I successfully generated the elf file, I checked the contents of .text.ssc_entry in main.o and 。test in elf.
[image: content]
They are identical on the right two bytes, but have different left two bytes.
I wonder if this is a normal result or something went wrong to cause this result

Comment: Down-vote for ignoring the advice given in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75065512/how-to-refresh-the-cpu-cache-in-the-embedded-linux-systemarm-linux) regarding images versus text.

Answer (score 0):

> They are identical on the right two bytes, but have different left two bytes.

If by "left two bytes" you mean the (two-byte) file offset, and the "right two bytes" you mean the 16-byte file contents, then yes: everything is working as expected here: in the linked file the location of the `.test` section is different from the location of the `.text.scc_entry` in the `main.o`.